# Adding docstrings to python functions pulled from dll using ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, docstring

I'm trying to create a bunch of python functions from a windows dll, and would like to have docstrings attached to each new function.

My current code:

```
import ctypes

lib=ctypes.WinDLL('example.dll')

VCS_OpenDevice=lib['VCS_OpenDevice']
VCS_OpenDevice.restype=ctypes.c_double
```

When i run this script in my interpreter and try to use the function, I get the 'no docstring' message.

Can't figure out to add something there. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your code imports a function, but then immediately replaces it with `ctypes.c_double`! >>> VCS_OpenDevice=lib['VCS_OpenDevice'] >>> VCS_OpenDevice=ctypes.c_double >>> print VCS_OpenDevice <class 'ctypes.c_double'>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign to the `__doc__` attribute of `ctypes` function pointers:

```
VCS_OpenDevice.__doc__ = 'My docstring'
```

`__doc__` is the docstring attribute of Python objects, and `ctypes` objects allow you to write to this attribute.

Obligatory libc demonstration (I use Mac, not Windows, but the principle is the same):

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.dylib") 
>>> libc.time.__doc__ = 'time -- get time of day'
>>> print libc.time.__doc__
time -- get time of day
```

IPython seems to be able to pick that up just fine:

```
In [4]: libc.time?
Type:       _FuncPtr
String Form:<_FuncPtr object at 0x1054b8ef0>
File:       /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py
Docstring:  time -- get time of day
```

Comment: Whilst you can assign `__doc__`, what you assign to that attribute does not appear when you do `help(...)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Bah, humbug, neither it does. Still, would IPython use it? And `oblig.` as abbreviation is obligatory, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: Well, I have no probs with oblig. but hey, not everyone speaks fluent English. Sometimes even I don't! Not sure about that IPython GUI.

Comment: PythonWin picks it up too. +1 and well played sir. I guess `help()` is special!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The object is a python class (albeit one that inherits from the `CFuncPtr` C-defined type), so setting the idea that setting `__doc__` on it should be allowed isn't too far fetched. :-)

Comment: I know. I just used `help()` as my way to see whether the docstring flowed through. That was obviously a bad choice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Indeed, `pydoc` classifies this as 'other' (and not class, surprisingly) and thus doesn't even look for a `__doc__` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

BUT I WANT TO USE help()!!!!!

So instead of wining about the unfairness of life I created the help_support
module that, when imported, will allow you to use help on documented ctypes functions and structures.
It also allows you to document extra stuff like names of ctypes function arguments and they will be displayed too.

https://pypi.org/project/help-support/0.2/

If you ar making Python bindings then include help_support.py and import it to allow poor soles like me to develop faster with your lib.

Real documentation is pain in the A... and I am happy with original Python console.

After doing the obvious thing by adding the doc string to my functions from a C extension, seeing no result in help() and finding no solution on the internet I just couldn't bare such a situation.
So here you are. Now you can use help() on functions pulled from a DLL (in Python 2 at least).

Here's an example:

```
# examp_module:
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

import help_support
del help_support # If you want you can remove it now
                 # to avoid cluttering your globals() namespace.
                 # Once it is called you do not usually need it any more.

l = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library("c"))

# Pull the time() function from libc,
# declare and document it:
time = l.time
time.argtypes = []
#time.argnames = ["c_void"] # The function takes no arguments, but you can trick help_support 
                            # to show something in parenthesis if you want to be consistent with C
                            # If there is/are argument(s) you should put its/their name(s) in "argnames".
time.restype = ctypes.c_int
time.__doc__ = "Function that returns a system time in seconds."
-------------------------------------------
>>> # Usage:
>>> import examp_module
>>> help(examp_module)
>>> help(examp_module.time)
>>>
```